# Can I make channel list with youtube API if I do not own the channel? I don't receive error but nothing display?

Tags: javascript, json, youtube-api

I am trying to make channel list, make a playlist of videos from the channel of Music, i do not own the channel here it is https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ/featured , what i want is to retrieve data from channel I do not own, however.

I thought I succeed when i did this: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&key=AIzaSyCKhEoBd9nZsMAC77NKQqf403mXnXTz35s&part=snippet,contentDetails

but when I try to put the videos on my html, nothing shows up, this is the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get (
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&key=AIzaSyCKhEoBd9nZsMAC77NKQqf403mXnXTz35s&part=snippet,contentDetails",
function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
        console.log(item);
        pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;

        getVids(pid);
    })
 }
 );

 function getVids(pid) { 
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", {
            part:'snippet',
            maxResults: 5,
            playlistId: pid,
            key: 'AIzaSyCKhEoBd9nZsMAC77NKQqf403mXnXTz35s'
        },

            function(data) {
                var output;
                $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    videTitle = item.snippet.title;

                    output = '<li>'+vidsTitle+'</li>'
                    $('#results').append(output);
                })
            }
        )
}
});
```

**I am receiving no error but the title is not displaying on HTML?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
you can use the parameter [`onBehalfOfContentOwner`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters), this parameter can only be used in a properly authorized request.

The `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter indicates that the request's authorization credentials identify a YouTube CMS user who is acting on behalf of the content owner specified in the parameter value. This parameter is intended for YouTube content partners that own and manage many different YouTube channels. It allows content owners to authenticate once and get access to all their video and channel data, without having to provide authentication credentials for each individual channel. The CMS account that the user authenticates with must be linked to the specified YouTube content owner.

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
```

If successful, this method returns a response body with the following structure:

```
{
"kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
"etag": etag,
"nextPageToken": string,
"prevPageToken": string,
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": integer,
"resultsPerPage": integer
},
"items": [
channel Resource
]
}
```

The document shows sample code with different supported programming languages: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#examples